# How do I take a given number of lists of numbers as input, if I do not know how many number are there in each list?

Tags: c++, user-input

https://www.spoj.com/problems/TTRGRAPH/

I was trying to solve the above problem, in the input specifications, it's given that there will be N lines of numbers (each line may have more than 1 numbers). How do I take the input (I am using C++)? I tried to take the input as shown below, but all of the numbers are getting pushed into the first vector.

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<vector<int>> g(n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        int e;
        while(cin>>e and e!='\n')
            g[i].push_back(e);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<g[i].size()<<' ';
    return 0;
}
```

For the input:

4

1 2 3

0 2 3

0 1 3

0 1 2

The output I am getting is:

12 0 0 0

But the expected output should be:

3 3 3 3

It would be helpful if someone can suggest something useful! Thank you!

Comment: Reading an `int` skips over whitespace, including newlines, and only reads integers. Your comparison will be true if a number you read happens to be the representation of the newline character. Read about `std::getline`and `std::istringstream`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution is to use `cin.peek()`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    vector<vector<int>> g(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int e;
        while (cin >> e) {
            g[i].push_back(e);
            if (cin.peek() == '\n') break;
        }
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        cout << g[i].size() << ' ';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    vector<vector<string>> g(n);
    cin.ignore();
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        string e;
        getline(cin,e);
        stringstream ss;
        ss<<e;
        string temp;
        while(ss>>temp) g[i].push_back(temp);
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        cout<<g[i].size()<<' ';
    return 0;
}
```

for each value of n get all the inputs in the nth line and pass it to stringstream. Then extract each element from the stream and push it to the respective vector.

Answer (score -1):

This works with space between numbers in input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <istream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
   int n;
   std::cin>>n;
   std::vector<std::vector<int>> g(n);

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
   {
        int e;
        while (std::cin >> e) {

           if(std::cin.peek() == ' ')
           {
               g[i].push_back(e);
           }

           if (std::cin.peek() == '\n')
           {
               g[i].push_back(e);
               break;
           }
       }
       std::cin.clear();
       std::cin.ignore();
   }

   for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
       std::cout<<g[i].size()<<' ';

   return 0;
```

}